# Sub-numbering in an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmicx

How can I add sub steps to a numbered step in an algorithm as shown in the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Square Root Cubature Kalman Filter SRCKF}

  \textbf{Time update}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Factorize the state error covariance matrix 
      \begin{equation}
        P_{k-1|k-1} = S_{k-1|k-1}S_{k-1|k-1}^T
      \end{equation}  
    \State Evaluate the cubature points (i=1,2,...,$m = 2n_x$)
      \begin{equation}
        X_{i,k-1|k-1} = \hat{x}_{k-1|k-1} + S_{i,k-1|k-1}\zeta_i
      \end{equation}
    \State Evaluate the propagated cubature points through the process equation (i=1,2,...,$m = 2n_x$)
      \begin{equation}
      X_{i,k|k-1}^*=f(X_{i,k-1|k-1},u_{k-1})
      \end{equation} 
    \State Estimate the predicted state


    \State Estimate the predicted error covariance
      \begin{equation}
      P_{k|k-1}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m{X_{i,k|k-1}^*X_{i,k|k-1}^{*T}}-\hat{x}_{k|k-1}\hat{x}_{k|k-1}^T+Q_{k-1} 
      \end{equation} 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many `algorithm` - related packages. We need a compilable code to work with, not just a `screenshot`

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer, I have updated my edition by inserting the Latex source code.

Comment: @user137684: I've updated your post with only the relevant code pertaining to your problem. All we ask is that you provide code that recreates the issue, not supply a full preamble of unrelated packages and a document filled with multiple algorithms and references... see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) and [What makes a good MWE?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/5764)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list-like environment `algsubstates` like I defined below. The enumeration formatting matches that of the regular `\State` (using `\footnotesize`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\newcounter{algsubstate}
\renewcommand{\thealgsubstate}{\alph{algsubstate}}
\newenvironment{algsubstates}
  {\setcounter{algsubstate}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\State}{%
     \stepcounter{algsubstate}%
     \Statex {\footnotesize\thealgsubstate:}\space}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Square Root Cubature Kalman Filter SRCKF}

  \textbf{Time update}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Factorize the state error covariance matrix 
      \begin{equation}
        P_{k-1 \mid k-1} = S_{k-1 \mid k-1} S_{k-1 \mid k-1}^T
      \end{equation}  
    \State Evaluate the cubature points ($i = 1,2,\ldots,m = 2n_x$)
      \begin{equation}
        X_{i,k-1 \mid k-1} = \hat{x}_{k-1 \mid k-1} + S_{i,k-1 \mid k-1} \zeta_i
      \end{equation}
    \State Evaluate the propagated cubature points through the process equation ($i = 1,2,\ldots,m = 2n_x$)
      \begin{equation}
        X_{i,k \mid k-1}^* = f(X_{i,k-1 \mid k-1},u_{k-1})
      \end{equation} 
    \State Estimate the predicted state
      \begin{algsubstates}
        \State First
        \State Second
        \State Third
        \State Last
      \end{algsubstates}
    \State Estimate the predicted error covariance
      \begin{equation}
      P_{k \mid k-1} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_{i,k \mid k-1}^* X_{i,k \mid k-1}^{*T}
        - \hat{x}_{k \mid k-1}\hat{x}_{k \mid k-1}^T + Q_{k-1} 
      \end{equation} 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The above code doesn't allow for referencing within the `algsubstates`. However, the following should:

```
\newcounter{algsubstate}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thealgsubstate}{\arabic{ALG@line}.\alph{algsubstate}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{algsubstates}
  {\setcounter{algsubstate}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\State}{%
     \refstepcounter{algsubstate}%
     \Statex {\footnotesize\alph{algsubstate}:}\space}}
  {}
```

`\ref`erences will be of the form `<state>.<substate>` (but could be changed).

Comment: Werner, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This method returns a warning "destination with the same identifier (name{algsubstate.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored" if used multiple times in the same document. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @permanganate: Consider [this alternative set of definitions](https://pastebin.com/raw/Mie4YWNA). You need a redefinition of `\theHalgsubstate` as well.

Comment: First of all, thank you for this little macro, I have been using this for a while! However, now I am required to use an alternative environment, and I cannot make this work under `algorithmic`  (instead of `algpseudocode`). I tried replacing `\State` by `\STATE` etc., but Latex just wouldn't accept `{\arabic{ALG@line}`, and I am out of ideas. Do you perhaps have some pointers on how to do this in `algorithmic`?

Comment: @Rolf: Can you post a small, [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) on [Pastebin](//pastebin.com) and share the link here? That way I can copy-and-paste it and replicate your problem. It'll help me identify how to provide a solution.

Comment: @Werner https://pastebin.com/BdUc9TBc thank you! Option 1 is your solution for `algpseudocode`, Option 2 would be a solution for `algorithmic`, if working.

Comment: @Rolf: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/37gY33y5).

Comment: @Werner thank you, it worked!

Comment: Hi, What if we have nested algosubstates?

Comment: @user3582228: Yeah, that's going to be an issue, since they would use the same counter. How many levels do you need?

Comment: @Werner I only need two levels.